# How can I get input variables to be stored in a sqlite3 table?

Tags: python, database, variables, sqlite

I am trying to get the user input the information so it can be stored in a database using SQLite3 but the error: "*sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: first_name*" keeps popping up and I don't know why. Any suggestions?

```
    import sqlite3

    connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    create_table = '''
    CREATE TABLE example (
    fname VARCHAR(20),
    lname VARCHAR(30),
    gender CHAR(1));'''
    cursor.execute(create_table)

    first_name = input('First name : ')
    surname = input('surname: ')
    gend = input('Gender: ')

    add_staff = '''INSERT INTO example (fname, lname, gender)
        VALUES (first_name, surname, gend);'''
    cursor.execute(add_staff)

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM example')
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for r in result:
        print(r)
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM example')
```

I would like to stick to sqlite3 rather than using another database library within python. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the values of your variables to your SQL command, using placeholders.

```
add_staff = '''INSERT INTO example (fname, lname, gender)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?);'''
cursor.execute(add_staff, (first_name, surname, gend))
```